# How do I get directionsService to display the route on the map (Google Maps API)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I'm quite new to Google maps and I'm trying to get my code to display a route that passes through 4 optimized waypoints.  My code is based off of the DirectionsService example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints), yet I can't seem to understand what I'm missing to make my code work.  I've been through the example code numerous times and it doesn't seem to me that I'm missing anything.  Currently my code only displays the markers that I set in the first part of the code.  Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
        //map details, i.e. creates a map of Lucca
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.8430,10.5050),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};



//create map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

//marker details
var markerOptions1 = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8402250, 10.5008083)
};
var markerOptions2 = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( 43.83811, 10.50328)
};
var markerOptions3 = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8439194, 10.5032083)
};
var markerOptions4 = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8405167, 10.5038722)
};

//creates markers
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions1);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions2);
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions3);
var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions4);

//sets markers
marker1.setMap(map);
marker2.setMap(map);
marker3.setMap(map);
marker4.setMap(map);

//marker info windows
var infoWindowOptions1 = {
    content: '1'
};

var infoWindowOptions2 = {
    content: '2'
};

var infoWindowOptions3 = {
    content: '3'
};

var infoWindowOptions4 = {
    content: '4'
};

//Events for clicking on the markers
var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions1);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1,'click',function(e){
  infoWindow1.open(map, marker1);
});

var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions2);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2,'click',function(e){
  infoWindow2.open(map, marker2);
});

var infoWindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions3);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker3,'click',function(e){
  infoWindow3.open(map, marker3);
});

var infoWindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions4);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker4,'click',function(e){
  infoWindow4.open(map, marker4);
});



/*  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });
} */


var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

function initialize() {
      // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map
      }
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions)

     // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
      //stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}




function calcRoute() {

    var waypts = [];

    stop = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8402250, 10.5008083)
    waypts.push({
        location: stop,
        stopover: true
    });
    stop = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.83811, 10.50328)
    waypts.push({
        location: stop,
        stopover: true
    });
    stop = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8439194, 10.5032083)
    waypts.push({
        location: stop,
        stopover: true
    });
    stop = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8405167, 10.5038722)
    waypts.push({
        location: stop,
        stopover: true
    });

    start = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.6038722);
    end = new google.maps.LatLng(43.8405167, 10.6038722);

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

Comment: you should call calcRoute();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still produced the same result (i.e. just the markers).

Comment: If you could provide with  a fiddle, it will help in answering better

Comment: Oh, sorry: https://jsfiddle.net/emvee/2ju8x0t9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it this way, if I´ve understand the question correct.
First you will need a polyLine:

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: "#58FA58",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    });
```

Now you just have to run through your result of the directionService, and fill the polyLine. This can be done this way:

```
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 service.route({
        origin: startAddress,
        destination: endAddress,
        waypoints: wayPoints,
        region: "DE",
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        //console.log(response.routes[0].legs);
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    //console.log(steps[j].instructions);
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                        poly.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong" + status);
        }
     });
```

Finally set the polyLine on the map:

```
poly.setMap(map).
```

That should do it.

I´m not sure if there are any significantly differences, by not using the DirectionsRender for that task, but this provided code paints a route between two points considering the given waypoints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any chance you can show me an example of some working code that implements this solution? I've made an attempt (https://jsfiddle.net/emvee/spxzLv5e/1/) but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you very much! Was it simply due to the variables "bounds" being undefined? Also - you mentioned a developers console: I'm new to jsfiddle and Javascript in general, how am I able to view it?

Comment: @emvee yeah I forgot to point that out, I have updated my answer code. It´s the same console you should use anywhere when doing web dev. In Chrome for example F12

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again!